# How to set AzCopy verbose log to the Console directly?

Tags: azure, azcopy

I'm using `AzCopy 8.1.0-netcore` on Windows. The `/V:[verbose-log-file]` option can only append verbose log to a file. I'd like to output verbose to the Console directly. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferable way to save the log as a file, since there could be a lot of useful information.

if any transfer ever goes wrong. AzCopy resume a job, AzCopy will attempt to transfer all of the files that are listed in the plan file which weren't already transferred. One option would be to save the log file in the current directory, or you can change the location of log file using Azcopy env : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-configure

~/.azcopy/plans contains the state files that allow AzCopy to resume failed jobs. They also allow the user to list all the jobs that ran in the past and query their results with ./azcopy jobs list and `./azcopy jobs show [job-ID]. We currently do not have a strategy to get rid of these files, as we don't know how long the user wants to keep records of their old jobs.

Logs are critical in helping our customers to investigate issues, as they could be very verbose and offer loads of useful information.
We can certainly add some kind of clean command that gets rid of these logs and plan files.

So as for workaround you can use azcopy jobs clean to remove the older logs and plan files.

Refer the document has same discussion did regarding the same:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/221